# How to properly add multiple form elements in a loop?

Tags: forms

I have a form where I need to loop through an array and display multiple form elements in a specific area.

Example:

```
$form_layout = 'Some html';
$form_layout .= '<div>';

foreach($something as $key => $value) {
    $form_layout .= 'some html';
    $form_layout .= 'some html';

    // I need this to be displayed in between the above and below code
    // in the layout
    $form['awesome_element'] => array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => 5,
        '#value' => 0
    );

    $form_layout .= 'some html';
    $form_layout .= 'some html';
}

$form_layout .= '</div>';
$form_layout .= 'Some html';

$form['some-other-awesomeness'] = array(
    // ...
    '#prefix' => $form_layout,
);
```

Doing it like the example puts the textfields after all the other page elements. I have tried using #prefix and #suffix but that breaks the layout even worse.

Any ideas on what I should do?

Edit: For clarity...

If I had layout elements such as a div tag I need my form elements, such as textfields, to be inserted in between those div tags.

So I need it to output something like this:

```
<div>
FORM ELEMENT
FORM ELEMENT
FORM ELEMENT
</div>
```

Instead it is outputting something like this:

```
<div></div>
FORM ELEMENT
FORM ELEMENT
FORM ELEMENT
```

Hopefully that is more clear, sorry if the above is confusing. Looking at code for the last 20 hours.

Edit2: added some visual stuff to make it easier to understand

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just me..but this doesn't seem to make much sense?!?

Comment: How would you like me to clarify? There is a layout, there are many form elements that are populated via an array which I extract with a foreach loop. I need those elements in between the layout elements.

Comment: No they are not the same... the div tag is ABOVE the form elements. I need the form elements IN BETWEEN the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do something like the following:

```
$form['openingdiv'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<div>'
);

//Do all your foreach stuff here

$form['closingdiv'] = array(
  '#markup' => '</div>'
);
```

(Sorry it's a bit simple..I'm tired :-p)

Comment: Probably needs `'#type' => 'markup'` as well.

Comment: What is this 'markup'? I am going to go look this up now... I will let you know if that looks promising. Thank you! :)

Comment: `'#type' => 'markup'` is the default type in D7, so no need.

Comment: @Baysaa It doesn't, if no `#type` is provided Drupal defaults to using `markup`

Comment: Ok, this is totally my fault! Your answer is exactly what I would need for the question I asked. Unfortunately though, I have not asked the question properly. Instead of editing more and possibly becoming more confusing I will just accept this and re-ask the question after some sleep lol Thank you for the quick answer!!!